# Async_Sinatra in Rails: async actions can't write to shared session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, asynchronous, sinatra, eventmachine

I have a Sinatra class in a Rails project.  It uses eventmachine and async_sinatra to make asynchronous calls to external sites.  I'd like to write to a session object (ideally, the same one that Rails is using), but so far I can only:

- write to a separate session object from Rails' (by default, Sinatra names its session something different from Rails)
- write to the same session for **synchronous calls only**

When I make asynchronous calls, sessions written in the async_sinatra code don't get pushed out to the client machine.  I suspect one of two things is happening:

- The header has already been sent to the client and the local variable storing the session (in Sinatra) will be flushed out at the end of the action.  The client would never see a request from the server to save this data to a cookie.
- The header *is* being sent to the client, but Rails immediate sends another, instructing the client to write to the cookie what Rails has stored in its `session` variable, overwriting what Sinatra wrote.

Either way, I'd like to just get simple session functionality in both Sinatra and Rails.  An explanation of what I'm doing wrong would also be nice :)

A full working copy of the code is [on github](https://github.com/eric-hu/AsyncSinatra-Rails-session-demo), but I believe the problem is specifically in this code:

```
class ExternalCall < Sinatra::Base
  use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore
  register Sinatra::Async  

  get '/sinatra/local' do
    session[:demo] = "sinatra can write to Rails' session"
  end

  aget '/sinatra/goog' do
    session[:async_call]="async sinatra calls cannot write to Rails' session"
    make_async_req :get, "http://www.google.com/" do |http_callback|
      if http_callback
        session[:em_callback] = "this also isn't saving for me" 
      else
        headers 'Status' => '422'
      end
      async_schedule { redirect '/' }

    end
  end


  helpers do
    def make_async_req(method, host, opts={}, &block)
      opts[:head] = { 'Accept' => 'text/html', 'Connection' => 'keep-alive' }
      http = EM::HttpRequest.new(host)
      http = http.send(method, {:head => opts[:head], :body => {}, :query => {}})
      http.callback &block
    end
  end
end
```

**EDIT 7/15**:

Changed code on Github to include Async-Rack.  Async-sinatra can write to sessions when they are **not** shared with Rails.  Compare the `master` and `segmented_sessions` branches for behavior difference.  (Or on the `master` branch, change `use ActionDispatch::Session::CookieStore` to `enable :sessions`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `async_sinatra` uses `throw :async` by default, effectively skipping the session middleware logic for storing stuff. You could override [async_response](https://github.com/raggi/async_sinatra/blob/v0.5.0/lib/sinatra/async.rb#L109-112) like that:

```
helpers do
  def async_response
    [-1, {}, []]
  end
end
```

Comment: hm, this doesn't seem to be working for me.  I've tried to do this in my own code as well as monkey-patching `async_sinatra` for this project.  I noticed in `async_sinatra` code you linked to that `aget` specifically schedules a get and a head separately.  I wonder if this could be causing the issue.  I believe that only one header can be sent back per request.  My coworkers decided to go with some kind of server-side session, but I'd still like to figure this out to hopefully make EM and Async_sinatra more usable.

Comment: Oh, yeah, just realized it, too. Headers are still ignored. Try using [async-rack](https://github.com/rkh/async-rack).

Comment: It turns out that we were actually using that in our main app and I forgot to include it in this demo project.  I've updated my demo project on Github as well as my question.  The demo code demonstrates that there's a session-sharing issue even when all middleware is called.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you use the Rails session middleware. The issue is: Your session middleware does not know how to handle async requests. With `throw :async` the code for generating the cookie simply never runs, with `[-1, {}, []]` that code will modify a headers hash that Thin will never use. I think you won't be able to fix this without getting your hands dirty in Rails and Rack code.

Comment: I think there is another solution: You could try storing a reference to the hash passed in `[-1, {}, []]` and later merge that into your session hash. But if any middleware returns a new hash instead of modifying that one, your SOL.

Comment: Or you could create a middleware wrapping everything that somehow stores that hash.